# Infinix Hot 2 (X510) on Android 6.0 doesn't show names when receiving a call

Tags: calls, 6.0-marshmallow, infinix-hot-2

My boss in the office asked me to help him upgrade his Infinix Hot 2 (X510) OS to Android 6.0 Marshmallow which I did. But after upgrading the phone, I discovered that when calls come in, it would only show the number but not the name.

How to fix it?

Comment: Seems a known issue: [1](http://www.nairaland.com/2532812/infinix-hot-2-x510-official/180#42285108), [2](http://mobilityarena.com/update-infinix-hot-2-android-6-marshmallow/)

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Shelaf.com](http://www.shelaf.com/2016/01/how-to-fix-android-60-bugs-on-your.html), you need to remove and re-add the Google Accounts and wait for them to resync.

> **Common Problems and Their Solutions**
>
> **Problem 1: Contact not displaying names after making or receiving a call**
> Go to your Google Settings and remove all Google accounts. After some minutes, add them back and your problem should be fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

The android marshmallow OS on the infinix hot 2 has quite a lot of bugs. In my opinion, the best option would be [downgrading back to Android Lollipop](http://www.techsng.com/2016/01/downgrade-infinix-hot-2-x510-running-6-0-marshmallow-to-5-1-android-lollipop.html). You can always choose to re-upgrade when the OS becomes more stable on the device.